# Angular 16 - Passing results of PapaParse ngx to API submission

Tags: arrays, angular, csv, parsing

Scenario: Import a csv for load via API to DynamoDB. I have a working API that works when taking the input via form. Now I want to bulk load via csv.

I'm using ngx-papapare to bring in the data. I can get a results object that correctly contains the array of objects, but when passing it to my API submit function, the array shows empty.

I've added a couple of console logs and commented what they show. As you can see, at the point of the end of papaParseCompleteFunction the "clubsToLoad" array contains the four array objects from the CSV. Here's the console output for 1 object in the array.

```
0
: 
clubID
: 
2
clubName
: 
"Newnham Archery Club"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

However, when returning the "data" object in the SubmitToDB function,, it's blank.

Here's the csv-loader component.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { APIService, Club } from 'src/app/services/api/API.service';
import { Papa, ParseResult } from 'ngx-papaparse'; 

@Component({
  'templateUrl': './csv-loader.component.html',
  'selector': 'app-csv-loader'
})

export class CsvLoader {

  public clubsToLoad : Array<Club> = [];

  constructor(private api: APIService, private papa: Papa) {}

  parseCsvFile(file: File) {
    this.papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      skipEmptyLines: "greedy",
      worker: true,
      complete: this.papaParseCompleteFunction
    });
  }


  papaParseCompleteFunction(results: ParseResult) {
    console.log("Completed Results", results);
    this.clubsToLoad = results.data as Club[];
    console.log("clubsToLoad",this.clubsToLoad);
    /*clubsToLoad has correct array of 4 objects */
  }
  
  handleFileSelect($event: any) {
    const fileList = $event.srcElement.files;
    this.parseCsvFile(fileList[0]);
    }
 
  submitToDB(data: any){
    console.log(data);
    /* data array is now empty  - called from onclick event*/
    for (let d of data) {
        console.log(d);
        this.onCreate(d);
      }
      
      }

      public onCreate(club: Club) {

        this.api
          .CreateClub(club)
          .then((event) => {
            console.log('item created!');
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log('error creating club...', e);
          });
      }
    }
```

Here's the onlick event in the html:

```
<div class="form-element">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="button" (click)="submitToDB(clubsToLoad)">Submit File</button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say instead of sending the data from template you can direct use the this.clubsToLoad in the .ts file as the codebase is in the same
It might be the case that angular is not detecting the changes happened from papaParaeCompletionFunction, you can try using detectChanges method. I will try these solutions and update the answer in sometime